# Does Locate Object work on polymorphed equipment?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The spell [*Locate Object*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/locate-object) says:

> You sense the direction to the object's location, as long as that object is within 1,000 feet of you.

The spell [*Polymorph*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/polymorph) says:

> The target's gear melds into the new form. The creature can't activate, use, wield, or otherwise benefit from any of its equipment.

If the object targeted by *Locate Object* has been "melded into the new form" of a polymorphed person will *Locate Object* succeed?

On one hand you could say the item, eg a spear, temporarily doesn't exist and so cannot be located.

On the other hand spells only do what they say they do and *Polymorph* does not say is hides items from being detected.

Comment: Related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/171264/43856

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, locate object will still work. The item doesn't cease to exist, but it "melds into the new form". So while they may not be able to find the exact location on that form, the spell would still lead them to the polymorphed creature.